# ¿Como acceder y obtener los elementos de una matriz en Angular 6 o 7?

Tags: json, angular, matrices

Soy primerizo en Angular, en la cual actualmente estoy trabajando en una aplicación con Angular7 en la cual me complico la vida al querer obtener desde el usuario.json datos del campo **"data"**, por ejemplo quisiera obtener desde el arreglo **"data"** su id, first_name, etc. Y asi poder recorrerlo y mostrar en una tabla desde el HTML.

¿Hay alguna mejor manera de hacerlo?

**USUARIO.JSON**

```
{
"page": 1,
"per_page": 3,
"total": 12,
"total_pages": 4,
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
"first_name": "George",
"last_name": "Bluth",
"avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
},
{
"id": 2,
"email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
"first_name": "Janet",
"last_name": "Weaver",
"avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
},
{
"id": 3,
"email": "emma.wong@reqres.in",
"first_name": "Emma",
"last_name": "Wong",
"avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"
}
]
}
```

### Coloco avances de la aplicación.

**administrar-usuario-model.ts**

```
// INTERFACE DE USUARIO
interface ISUsuario {
    id?: number;
    email?: string;
    first_name?: string;
    last_name?: string;
    avatar?: string;
}
```

**administrar-usuario.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Url } from '../Clases/Url';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AdministrarUsuarioService {

  private OBTENER_USUARIOS: string = Url.RUTA_APP + '/api/users';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public obtener_usuarios(): Observable<any> {
    const ruta: string = this.OBTENER_USUARIOS;
    console.log('ruta', ruta);
    return this.http.get(ruta).pipe(map((data) =>
      console.log('DATA: ', data)),
      catchError(this.handleError('OBTENER_USUARIOS', []))
    );
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

**administracion-usuario.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AdministrarUsuarioService } from 'src/app/services/administrar-usuario.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-administracion-usuarios',
  templateUrl: './administracion-usuarios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./administracion-usuarios.component.css']
})
export class AdministracionUsuariosComponent implements OnInit {

  public listarTablaUsuario: ISUsuario[] = [];

  constructor(private servicio: AdministrarUsuarioService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ObtenerListaUsuario();
  }

  private ObtenerListaUsuario() {
    this.servicio.obtener_usuarios().subscribe(data => {
      if (data != null) {
        this.listarTablaUsuario = data;
        console.log(this.listarTablaUsuario, ' TABLA USUARIO');
      } else {
        this.listarTablaUsuario = [];
      }
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

**administrar-usuario.html**

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let usuario of listarTablaUsuario.data">
          <td>{{usuario.id}}</td>
          <td>{{usuario.email}}</td>
          <td>{{usuario.first_name}}</td>
          <td>{{usuario.last_name}}</td>
          <td>{{usuario.avatar}}</td>
          <td>
            <a href="#editarUsuarioModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal">
              <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar">&#xE254;</i>
            </a>
            <a href="#detalleUsuarioModal" class="detail" data-toggle="modal">
              <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Detalle">&#xe0ee;</i>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

***Agrego el resultado con las tablas vacías***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería bastante su ayuda....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOGRE RESOLVERLO

```
public obtener_usuarios(): Observable<any> {
    const ruta: string = this.OBTENER_USUARIOS;
    console.log('ruta', ruta);
    return this.http.get(ruta).pipe(map((data: any) => data.data),
      catchError(this.handleError('OBTENER_USUARIOS', []))
    );
  }
```

Ya que en el json tenia que entrar al campo data, entonces por lógica tenía que aplicar data.data para poder acceder asu valores.

Esta pregunta esta resuelta igualmente gracias.

Comment: Cuando te sea posible recuerda aceptar tu respuesta para que se identifique como que ya se encontró la solución

Answer (score 0):

No tengo suficientes puntos para comentar,

Creo que el problema lo tienes aquí y es tan simple, cómo que sólo haces el console.log de DATA y es el retorno del Observable que hace cúando es llamado en NgOnInit del componente que quiere "subscribe" así que tú funcion ObtenerListaUsuario siempre acaba en el else del NULL con la lista vacía.

```
public obtener_usuarios(): Observable<any> {
    const ruta: string = this.OBTENER_USUARIOS;
    console.log('ruta', ruta);
    return this.http.get(ruta).pipe(map((data) =>
      **console.log('DATA: ', data)**),
      catchError(this.handleError('OBTENER_USUARIOS', []))
    );
  }
```

> Prueba a cambiar:
>
> **console.log('DATA: ', data)**
>
> por simplemente :
>
> data